# В ветку попали изменения в мастере

Tags: git

Через веб-версию создал файл с `readme.md` для установки под Ubuntu. Потом зашёл через консоль на удалённый сервер, сделал там изменения, создал ветку, в неё засунул изменённый файл, сделал `git commit`, `git push` новой ветки. А в коммите теперь отображается readme.md, который я в ветку не вставлял. Что я сделал не так и как это исправить?

Comment: А что не так? Как, по вашему, должно было быть?

Comment: @gil9red ну я же выкатывал только файлы в созданной ветке.

Comment: Вы создали ветку, т.е. взяли все коммиты от мастера. Добавили в ветку файл и после закоммитили. Или в ветку попал другой, второй файл?